# Does cutting off the legs count as a kill?

Tags: state-of-decay, state-of-decay-yose

For edges weapons and heavy weapons, there are specialization moves that cut off the legs from the zombies, the zombie doesn't die straight away but it despawns after a second or two.

Does this count as a kill for the Combat Rage ability?
Or is an execution move required to actually get the killing animation to count?

Answer (score 1):

Cutting off a zombie's legs with the leg sweep kill will render the zombie immobile, harmless, and lead to it's death within 10 seconds.

While not as immediate as an execution the zombie will die. For this reason the leg sweep is considered very useful as it's faster and more flexible than the decapitation specialization while producing the same results.